# Set Builder Notation Practice

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, notation

I have a Math Homework Quiz on set builder notation, I'm nearly certain of all my answer being correct, but I only have one attempt and there is no time limit so I would like someone to point out my mistakes.

1. If $n$ is an integer, then $2n$ is an even number. **TRUE**
2. Let $A = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$, $B = \{x: x = 2k \text { for some } k \in \mathbb{N} \}$, $C = \{x \in \mathbb{N} : x<6\}$. Here $\mathbb{N} = \{1,2,3,4 ...\}$

a) $\{4,3,2\} \subseteq A$. **TRUE**

b) $3 \in B$. **FALSE**

c) $\{2\} \in B$. **FALSE**

d) $A = C$ **TRUE**

e) $C \subseteq B$ **FALSE**

3. $\exists x \in [2,4] \hspace{1mm}s.t \hspace{2mm}x<7$ **TRUE**
4. $\forall x \in [2,4] \hspace{1mm}s.t \hspace{2mm}x<7$ **TRUE**

I am not sure about the last 2. But since there are only two members of the given set the quantifiers $\forall \hspace{1mm}or\hspace{1mm} \exists$ shouldn't make a difference anyway but I am not still sure.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's from an ongoing assessment.

Comment: This question is currently under discussion at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35136/is-a-math-quiz-worth-overlooking-the-rules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There aren't two members in the set $\left[2,4\right]$. That set is an interval containing all the real numbers between $2$ and $4$. It's denoted by $2 \leq x \leq 4$. With that in mind,

3. is true because you can pick some number, like $3$ or $3.4$ for instance, from that interval and see that it's less than $7$.
4. is the one that's bothering me, though. Can you check to see if it's written correctly? Because the way I'm reading it, it translates as

"For all $x$ in $\left[2,4\right]$ such that $x$ is less than $7$."

That doesn't seem to be a full sentence. If it said "For all $x$ in $\left[2,4\right]$, $x$ is less than $7$," or equivalently, $\forall x \in \left[2,4\right]$, $x < 7,$ then it's true because you can pick any number from that interval and see it's less than $7$.

(Also, I checked the other answers out of curiosity. They're all correct.)